# How to add configurable product (5000) in Magento? I have upload only 1 Days

Tags: magento, product, configurable

I have upload 5000 configurable product in Magento only 1 Days. Please specific how to upload CSV or xls auto create csv product simple with configurable product. By code or "Magento connect plugin".

Two attribute add **size** and **potency**. How to upload how to upload 5000 product generate automatic csv?

Comment: you can try magmi.

Answer (score 0):

Magento default import functionality allows to create configurables via import, though I tried 100 times, it is difficult and not so approachable. Magento connect offers lots of [plugins](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/store-manager-for-magento-professional-edition-1.html), it might be time-saving and efficient